# Adding Files to Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to add files to an Azure Blob using the code snippet

```
    async void archiveNewImportedImages(List<ImportedImageFile> imageFiles)
    {

        // Saving the images
        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".




        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\rahulchawla\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\CR01-1-20170623-1308.jpg"))
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }





    }
```

I'm trying to use the method UploadFromStream but i'm getting the error that cloudblockblob does not have an extension method and suggests Async. also i'm trying to add a test image there is an error in the file stream read/write timeout - Any Suggestions? this is a .net core console application

Comment: Trying changing this line of code `blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);` to `await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);` because it's an async method. Also the method where this code is written should be declared as `async` as well.

Comment: I originally wanted to use the methodUploadFromStream - however it says it doesnt exist but both the methods exist in cloudblockblob @GauravMantri

Comment: You can't as the .Net core version of the library has not implemented sync version of the methods. You will have to use async methods only.

Comment: is there a nuget package for async because it says it doesnt exist when I rename the method to async Task@GauravMantri

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete code for your method. You would need to include `using System.Threading.Tasks;` in your code to make use of `async`. HTH.

Comment: Fixed my method to be async void and added await in the method however when I debug the method the image is not being added to the blob and there is an exception throw on filesStream "ReadTimeout = 'fileStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'" and write timeout @GauravMantri

Comment: Which version of Storage Client library are you using? Let me give it a try.

Comment: Ahh It ended up working my Azure Server Explorer is giving me issues, quick question I am adding files and the past file is disappeared does it overwrite the blob? @GauravMantri

Comment: Yes it does overwrite.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for the method it seems like all the methods overwrite is there a way to make it so blob is not overwritten and keeps growing @GauravMantri

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question for this please?